# Black Screen when I click on Navigator.pop()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I have this app I want it to open a new page when I click on a button. It was working before when my second page is a stateless widget. But when I changed it to Stateful Widget , and clicked on the button , my entire screen turns black.

Problem :

[The Problem (PICTURE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aauwq.png)

And here is my code :

```
 class _MainBodyState extends State<MainBody> {
  Color lol = Colors.red;

  showMsg(msg) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(msg.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              "Welcome to",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 35,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "I d k what it is tbh",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Card(
                semanticContainer: true,
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                child: Container(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/3.jpg',
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
                elevation: 8,
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10),
              child: Text(
                "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  letterSpacing: 1.4,
                  height: 1.4,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
            Text(
              "Images",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Card(
                              semanticContainer: true,
                              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 200,
                                height: 200,
                                color: Colors.accents[i],
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/images/$i.jpg",
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                              elevation: 5,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                i.toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text(
                "CLICK FOR MAGIK",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  lol = Color(Random().nextInt(0xffffffff));
                });
              },
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: lol,
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text(
                "CLICK FOR NEW PAGE",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                showMsg("Open new page");
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()), <== The Open Second Page
                );
              },
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And This is my Second Screen code :

```
class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondRouteState createState() => _SecondRouteState();
}

class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigate back to first route when tapped.
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Go back!'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Both of my widget is Stateful ( Before that my second widget was Stateless and it works fine )**

Any help is appreciated , thanks !

***UPDATE : When I change my second widget back to stateless , It shows black screen and isn't working either***

Comment: The code is working fine and I can see the button in the picture, its just at the very top. You can wrap your build in a safe area widget to avoid to top alignment, and change the background color on container

Comment: If it works better for you, return a scaffold instead of container

Comment: @Texv thank you , I changed the Container to Scaffold and It worked ! Thanks man .

Comment: No problem. Please upvote my comment if it was useful. Happy coding :)